# I cant create a framework that work in xcode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa, ipad, frameworks

I have this library https://github.com/ararog/Unrar4iOS for unrar in IOS device
and i build, like the creator of the project say, but one files is missing and dont work when i importing to my project but if i use the framework that cames with the example work fine.
I need to compile but my self because the framework has a important leak of memory and i want to fix this issue.

I am using  xcode version 4.1 for snow leopard

Regards

Edit the error is:

```
Ld /Users/pacoflaco/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/prueba-dvzvrihnyniqghgnyjzjdvqvnvne/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/prueba.app/prueba normal i386

    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk -L/Users/pacoflaco/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/prueba-dvzvrihnyniqghgnyjzjdvqvnvne/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/pacoflaco/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/prueba-dvzvrihnyniqghgnyjzjdvqvnvne/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/pacoflaco/Proyectos/prueba -filelist /Users/pacoflaco/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/prueba-dvzvrihnyniqghgnyjzjdvqvnvne/Build/Intermediates/prueba.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/prueba.build/Objects-normal/i386/prueba.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreData -framework Unrar4iOS -o /Users/pacoflaco/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/prueba-dvzvrihnyniqghgnyjzjdvqvnvne/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/prueba.app/prueba


    ld: framework not found Unrar4iOS
    Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

The file missing is Unrar4iOS

Comment: What file does it think is missing?  What error do you get when you build?  There is not enough information here.

Comment: Sorry, i add some more information. When i build i have some warnings but there are for variables that are not used

Comment: @pacoflaco: Please edit your question to include the complete error message, including the command that produced it.

Comment: @pacoflaco: The command (by which I mean the line that includes all of the arguments) precedes the output. Please include the command.

Comment: @pacoflaco: did you ever resolve the issue??

Comment: @Alex1987, could you compile the framerok?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the folder that contains the Unrar4iOS framework among your Framework Search Paths, which is one of the build settings you can edit while editing the project object.

Comment: Yes i did, as i said if i use the framework that came with the example work fine but if i compile the framework and add this framework the xocde said me this error. Try to download the framework and compile but your self.

Comment: Whether you build it yourself doesn't matter (assuming it built successfully, so you're not trying to link against a half-formed husk of a framework). You need to include the path to the folder that contains the framework you built. That isn't in the command you showed, so you need to add it to your Framework Search Paths (or, assuming the framework is also built using Xcode, add the framework project as a subproject and add the framework as a dependent target and link against its product).

Comment: Yes i did, but when i compile by myself the framewwork has a size of 260kb and the framework that cames with the example has a one more file and the total of size is 4mb. That is the problem because when i copy the file to the framework work fine.